# Environment variable in Jenkins with dot in Java Maven Project

Tags: java, jenkins, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I have a Java program(Maven build) and which is using environment variable with dot(.) as mentioned below for Cloud Foundry, and my application has unit test that connect to vault/database while building artifact in Jenkins server

> vcap.services.dor.credentials.path

is there a way I can set these variable in Jenkins and get access in my java code while unit test?

Comment: Yes. Tell me, how do you run your tests from Jenkins? do you use Maven or Gradle or something else?

Comment: I use maven, I have 'mvn test -Dtest=\"com/packagename/ClassName_ITs**"' command in Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using the "Invoke top-level Maven targets":

[image]

$MY_VARIABLE comes from an input from your build. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Clarification: the image shows "mvn install" but in your case it would be "mvn test -Dtest=\"com/packagename/ClassName_ITs** -Dmy.dotted.variable....blablabla".